# Redis subscribe timeout

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, node-redis

How can i set timer function for Redis sub, so when client connect and message is not received from pubblisher in 200ms socket emit an event?

This is what i have now:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    const sub = redis.createClient();
    sub.subscribe("data");

    sub.on("message", function(channel, message) {
      io.emit("data", JSON.parse(message));
    });

    sub.on("error", function(err){
      console.log("Error" + err);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function(){
      sub.removeListerner('message', function(){
        io.emit("disconnected");
      })
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know its a late question but hopefully this answer can help someone else or if you still havent found one. You can use a timeout function that calls a handler function just in case the message isnt received (im guessing that's what your asking)

I'm using redis as well and I do a call to other databases to check if they have the user with the requested id. To make sure the user doesn't stay and wait I added a timeout function which I set to 500ms. so its a race condition and whichever comes first I unsubscribe the redis client to make sure its a one off as well.

```
return User.mongoose.findAsync({ _id: params.id })
.then ( results => {

    if (sails.IS.empty(results)) {

        const request_id = Date.now() + '@' + sails.HOST_NAME + '/user/' + params.id

        sails.REDIS_SUB.subscribe(request_id)

        sails.REDIS_SUB.on('message', (channel, message) => {
        if (channel == request_id) {

            const data = JSON.parse(message)

            sails.dlogwarn(params.id + '\t<=\t(' + data.responder + ')')

            sails.REDIS_SUB.unsubscribe(request_id)

            return data.params.results
        }
  })

  sails.REDIS_PUB.publish('/user/find', JSON.stringify({
      request_id: request_id,
      params: {
          _id: params.id
      }
  }))

  setTimeout( () => {
      sails.REDIS_SUB.unsubscribe(request_id)
      return results
  }, Number(process.env.REDIS_MAX_QUERY_TIMEOUT))

} else return results
})
```